# NTLM authentication issue in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, ntlm

I want to connect to the server which supports NTLM authentication. I read knowledge article “How To - Implement basic HTTP authentication” on Blackberry developers site, however I did not find any reference for NTLM authentication.

Is Blackberry does not support NTLM authentication over HTTP connection? Any work-around?

Comment: Vishal, I do android. But use jcifs for ntlm authentication.  http://jcifs.samba.org/src/docs/httpclient.html   Maybe it will work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Blackberry does support NTLM authentication over HTTP with the aide of a Blackberry Server (BES) component called MDS-CS. The blackberry will pass credentials using basic authentication to the BES, which then will complete the NTLM handshake on behalf of the Blackberry. The only requirement is that Support HTTP Authentication is set to True in the MDS-CS settings on the BES.